# clone a image and then rename it using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to rename my image captured using camera at client side using javascript. I know it is not directly possible due to security reasons.

I already did it in server side but I need to rename my image before uploading to server. Can I make a copy of image and then rename it? If I can, how would I do it?

This is my javascript file

```
var oFile = new File([""],"");
var clonedImage = new Image();

//cloning function


function cloneImage ()
{
  alert("cloning1");

clonedImage.name = oFile.name;
document.getElementById("image_file").appendChild( clonedImage);

alert("cloning2");
alert("success" +clonedImage.name );
}

function fileSelected()
{
// get selected file element

oFile = document.getElementById('image_file').files[0];
// filter for image files

var rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
alert("Not a proper file format");
return;
}


cloneImage();
alert("cloning");

var oReader = new FileReader();
oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);

alert("success = "+oFile.name);
alert("success = "+oFile.type);


}


function startUploading()
{




var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById("upload_form"));
var imageName = oFile.name;
formdata.append("image1",oFile);


var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://10.182.xx.xx/upload.php',true);

alert("start uploading");
alert("success ="+oFile.name);



request.send(formdata);

alert("finished");


 }
```

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="file:///android_asset/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="file:///android_asset/script.js" type ="text/javascript">    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php">
        <div>
            <div><label for="image_file">Please select image file</label></div>
            <div><input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected()" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" name="image1" id="image1" value="Upload" onclick="startUploading()"/>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edited and added my code above

Comment: hi, it's better to do the rename inside your uplaod.php file.it's very simple.

Comment: I have already done that but for some reason I need it in javascript.

Comment: So I found how to do the cloning part. Can anyone suggest how to replace the name of the image. I edited my code above to include the cloning part.